# How to select random row from each group in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random

How to randomly get one row from each group in MySQL? 
for ex:

```
A 145 <br/>
A 589***********GROUP 1 <br/>
A 576 <br/>

B 246************GROUP 2 <br/>
B 456 <br/>

C 558 <br/>
C 478***********GROUP 3 <br/>
C 4756 <br/>
```

want to get any row from each group.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select N random records per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913779/select-n-random-records-per-group)

Comment: when I searched ,It was suggesting me to use "order by rand() method" which is very bad to use when there are more number of rows.

Comment: `SELECT ... GROUP BY group_idx ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` where is this bad?

Comment: @Lukas Have a try and you will see ;) it gives the wrong (and only one) result.

Comment: @Lukas `ORDER BY RAND()` has horrible performance with a large amount of rows.

Comment: @fancyPants Oh yes you are right, I should get a coffee before bothering people on SO in the morning.

Comment: i have got a solution using rand(),but i need alternative for rand()..query which I am using is select * from (select * from Tablename order by rand()) as t group by (fieldname);

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY rand()` calculates a random value at every read for every row. It is better to calculate a random sortorder once a day (or once an hour) for every row and store it in the detailed table, and for selecting the value just produce a temp-table with a compare-randomvalue for every category.

I just posted a solution in [Combining queries for speed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23464939/2277620).